# Is it possible in Tomcat/Java EE server to deploy app in RAM memory, to speed up development?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, deployment, ram

Even if we enable "deploy on save" with our IDE, we still need to wait some time to propagate changes. This can be annoying espacially when we deploy small changes.

**So, is it possible to run some servlet container in-memory with IDE-compatible deployment to speed up deployment and development time?** Or even run whole container in-memory with server dependencies (JSP compilator etc.).

(I know that I can install Tomcat on RAMDisk, but looking for "more native" solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According from their site

JRebel is a JVM-plugin that makes it possible for Java developers to instantly see any code change made to an app without redeploying. JRebel lets you see code changes instantly, versioning classes and resources individually and updating one at a time instead of as a lump application redeploy. When developers make a change to any class or resource in their IDE, the change is immediately reflected in the deployed application, skipping the build and redeploy phases and preventing an average of 5.25 work weeks per year in redeploys!

http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

Comment: JRebel can save a lot of time indeed. It can also cost time if there are problems configuring it, but still it's quite a nice product.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you can do is to set the deployment path to your webapps directory. This way you deploy the application "exploded" without copying the whole app to another deployment directory. Make sure to let the classes be compiled into the WEB-INF/classes directory.

A second, more problematic thing is, the class loader. When the JVM runs in debug mode, some code changes made within methods will be recognized by the class loader and you would see the changes immediately. But some changes, like method signature and structural class changes will not be detected, so a restart of the JVM will be necessary. You can provide a self brewed class loader which will be able to reload anything when the underlying class files changes.

Answer (score 0):

The tomcat container is loaded in memory when you start it. And tomcat loads all the applications available in webapps directory. Later as and when application classes are required are loaded. And application may load some other resources as required.

If you open the task manager on windows or similar thing on other OS, you can see that tomcat java process is always runnning once started.  You may also check its current memory footprint . So it is not unloaded and re-loaded on demand.